# Change corner radius of Imageview at runtime

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable

hello guys Here is my xml file. I want to change corner radius of Imageview at run time in such a way corner radius of bitmap in Imageview should be changed . Does anyone have idea that how can I perform this task.

```
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center"
   >

 <TableLayout 
     android:id="@+id/firstpicTable"
     android:layout_width="102.5dp"
     android:layout_height="200dp"
     android:background="@drawable/tableborder"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     android:padding="0.5dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
             >
              <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"

         android:background="@android:color/white"
         android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
         />


 </TableLayout>

  <TableLayout 
     android:id="@+id/secondtpicTable"
     android:layout_width="102.5dp"
     android:layout_height="200dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:background="@drawable/tableborder"
      android:padding="0.5dp"

     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstpicTable"
     >

     <ImageView 
         android:id="@+id/image223"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:focusable="true"
         android:background="@android:color/white"
         android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"

         />
 </TableLayout>

   <TableLayout 
     android:id="@+id/thirddtpicTable"
     android:layout_width="102.5dp"
     android:layout_height="200dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/secondtpicTable"
      android:padding="0.5dp"
      android:background="@drawable/tableborder"

     android:gravity="center">
     <ImageView 
         android:id="@+id/image3"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@android:color/black"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:focusable="true"
         android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"

         />
 </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Romain Guy wrote in his blog [1], you can draw a rounded image by implementing a `Drawable` and use `canvas.drawRoundRect()`

If you want to vary the corner radius at runtime, then you can update a property in your drawable (a integer like `mCornerRadius` for instance), and invoke `invalidateSelf()` to trigger the redraw.

[1] http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make shape in drawable and use in your ImageView   like this

**round_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>    

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"/>

    <padding android:left="1dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="1dp"
             android:bottom="1dp"/> 

    <corners android:radius="30dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Provide your own custom radius value under `corners` tag